# Binding border color to ListBox IsFocused property

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I change the colour of the border depending on whether the ListBox in the following code has focus:

```
<LisBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" x:Name="list"/>

<Border>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=list}"/>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DataTrigger` in `Border`'s style; and bind it to `ListBox`'s property (in this case I used `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`). When the `ListBox` loses focus, it will revert back to original color.

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyCollection}" x:Name="list"/>
    <Border BorderThickness="2">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Aquamarine" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, ElementName=list}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=list}"/>
    </Border>
```